How to correctly wire a PE Beam to trip a relay
I am trying to design a simple circuit using a Banner QS18 PE beam, which trips a relay when the PE beam is interrupted. I have experience with 12v automotive circuits, but I'm new to industrial components like this. I have wired up the system as per below:

Blue wires to +24v
Brown wires to Ground
white wire (QS18VP6R only) to Relay #1 coil
black wire (QS18VP6R only) to Relay #2 coil
opposite coils of both relays to +24v

For some reason, the QS18VP6R wiring diagram says to connect brown wire to +24v and blue wire to Ground, but when I do this the PE beams don't power up at all.
The relay #1 was just included to know when I'd powered the PE beams correctly, because I don't have an LED indicator handy. According to the manufacturer's wiring diagram, I would expect in my circuit that Relay #1 should be activated the whole time the PE beams have power, and Relay #2 should activate when I interrupt the PE beam. However, in actual fact both relays activate when I power up, and stay activated no matter how I position or interrupt the PE beams. I've verified 24v at the PSU, and verified the PE beams with a second set that do the same thing. What am I doing wrong?






no, 24v. -24v was meant to signify the negative terminal of the power supply - now edited to be Ground for clarity.

Your wiring is incorrect.
Here's the right way to wire the sensors.

'Brown (+ ve)' and 'Blue (- ve)' are standard cable colour codes for sensors.

Thanks, that fixed it! Any idea why the QS186E wiring diagram says brown should be negative and blue positive?

@KendricRendle-Short: As I read that diagram, brown, on terminal 1, is positive, and blue, on terminal 3, is negatiive.  Note that the pin numbers on the device drawing are not in numerical order, and don't match to order of the wires in the key list.

Anytime, Kendric! Thank you very much for your apt explanation, Peter.
